# Error While Saving videos offline on YouTube (unplayable)

Tags: video, youtube, offline

I tried to save videos offline on YouTube on my Android mobile (Vivo V3) and it said that the video couldn't be save offline due to an error, "Unplayable". What does this mean and how can I fix this?

Comment: you need to include more info like which country you are using app, is it happening for 1 video or all videos, was internet ON when you tried to do this etc.

Comment: @AADAndroidEnthusiasts Nepal, it's happening for a lot of videos. Of course I'm doing it online.

Answer (score 0):

Due to copyright reasons, YouTube does not allow offline playback except for YouTube red with certain content. Therefore, any app that is supposedly giving you offline access to YouTube without its paid services is doing so illegally, and you should not be surprised it is not working.